# Several downvotes today

Tags: support, down-votes

If I see that three old answers of mine on the Linguistics sitehave all been downvoted today, is it reasonable to suspect somebody is stalking me?

Comment: When someone is really stalking you, stackexchange has efficient scripts to detect and reverse such behaviour. They are typically run once a day. But with only three downvotes, the stalker may fly below the radar.

Comment: @jknappen Yes, if Colin Fine only has 3 answers and somebody downvoted all of them, the StackExchange community thinks that the votes are suspicious and they will revert all of them.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed possible that someone was checking out your profile in particular rather than just, by coincidence, several questions you have been answering, but with a mere 3 downvotes, I would certainly not by worried about stalking. Someone was interested in who that Colin Fine guy is, scrolled a bit through your posts, disagreed with three of them, that's it. I'm almost sure I've done a similar thing once or twice before and I certainly didn't mean to stalk these users, just casually checking out on what they write and cast my votes as I would normally do.

Answer (score 3):

That is possible: another alternative is that someone was reviewing a set of topics that you wrote on and disagreed with your answers. It depends how implausible it is that someone would encounter those answers.

Comment: True. I don't think they were on particularly related topics. Certainly the questions didn't have a single tag in common.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible that somebody might be stalking. Another alternative is that somebody was looking at a set of tags, and they disagreed all your answers when they looked on the 3 questions that have your answers in it on each tag.